# Changing DIV sizes based on Dynamically loaded images from database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

I have an online portfolio I am working on, I am fairly new at both JQuery and PHP, but am working my way through all the issues, however this one has me stumped.

So, I have a seamless iframe for loading my images from the navigation, I am trying to build it so that the images all line up horizontally, normally I would load everything and dynamically change the wrapper for the browsers viewport, however since the images are coming server side form a PHP script / mySQL database, I am unsure of how to alter any of the image or div contents.

Everything is a loaded in a While loop after a user selects which portfolio to view.

Here is a link: http://tbremer.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Let me know what other information is needed!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the width and height of an image from the server.
Ex:

$image_data = getimagesize(PATH_TO_IMAGE);
var_dump($image_data);

Better yet, you could use "list" to retrieve the width and height:

list($width,$height) = getimagesize(PATH_TO_IMAGE);

Whereas, the first two returns from the array are width then height, they are then set the the variables, oddly enough $width and $height, and you can use those to re-size your iframes.

Comment: I retrieve that data, and thought about that however the images are downsized for output so that they all maintain an equal height. So some images are wider and others are thinner.